# Why have my Visual Studio 2008 SP1 macros stropped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

I just cannot for the life of me figure out why my build event macro is no longer firing. Any ideas?

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module EnvironmentEvents

    Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone(ByVal Project As String, _
                                                ByVal ProjectConfig As String, _
                                                ByVal Platform As String, _
                                                ByVal SolutionConfig As String, _
                                                ByVal Success As Boolean) _
                                    Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone
        If Success = False Then
            'The build failed...cancel any further builds.
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.Cancel")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I don't actually know how VS knows which macro to trigger on events, but did you try to add a new macro for this event, and copy the code there ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Windows Update? Are all the macros not working or just this one?

Comment: no i haven't. but my machine is getting rebuilt in the next week. i'm going to wait and see if that has an effect. and maybe not have vs 2005 and vs 2008 side by side....